# Save var_export to MySql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script which executes a command on the server for example:

```
exec('sudo unoconv -f pdf '.$file, $output, $return);
```

Then I check if the script executed successfully:

```
if(!$return) { Do something here } else{ $errormsg = var_export($output, true); }
```

The error message might look something similar to this:

```
array ( 0 => 'Error: /invalidfileaccess in pdf_process_Encrypt', 1 => 'Operand stack:', 2 => '', 3 => 'Execution stack:', 4 => ' %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1910 1 3 %oparray_pop 1909 1 3 %oparray_pop 1893 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push', 5 => 'Dictionary stack:', 6 => ' --dict:1162/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:82/200(L)-- --dict:82/200(L)-- --dict:109/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:291/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:20/31(L)--', 7 => 'Current allocation mode is local', )
```

I then attempt to store the error message into my MySql database:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO incidents (operation, date, error) VALUES ('convert', '$date', '$errormsg')");
```

The column `error` is of data type VARCHAR(), when I execute the above query nothing is inserted into the database, if I remove `$errormsg` from the above command the data is successfully inserted into the database. Which data type should I use for the column so that the error message would be inserted?

Comment: The varable you are using for the sql statement is blank. Thats why the blank record. Until you show some real code everything is just a guess.

Comment: I updated my Question, I hope it would be more clear now.

Comment: Because you not using prepared statements. The SQL parser is interpretating the values in error. You basically SQL injecting your self. This is a bit of a primer http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: You are correct, the output of the error message contains () brackets and ' '  quotations, thus when trying to insert it into the database it interprets the brackets and quotation marks, thus "SQL injecting myself". Stupid mistake, I'm currently converting to prepared statements, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method seems to return a string. This code

```
<?php

$var = ['test' => 'ja'];
$result = var_export($var, true);
echo gettype($result);
```

prints "string" to output. So as I understood, this method returns valid PHP-Code as a string.

I would guess, that the problem is not related to this function but to the SQL-Query or code for storing the information.

Update: I saw, that you posted an update. The problem is, that you are neither escaping the string nor using prepared statements. I would recommend to you, that you use prepared statements instead of string interpolation. This is also relevant with regards to security problems.

See mysqli_real_escape_string or even better mysqli_prepare